# idangero.us swiper - resize error when image is bigger than window

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have this problem when I resize my window to a point where the image is bigger than it. When it happens, the current image is slightly cropped in the left side and the previous image appears. I have an image to show this: (turns out I can't post images!)
The green rectangle shows the normal image. Inside the red rectangle there is a small part of the previous image that is "pushing" the main one.

I tried changing the css and it appears that there is a miscalculation in the translate3d attribute, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function swipper_resize(){
    var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
        slidesPerView:4,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 20,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        autoplay: 3000,
        freeMode: true

    })
    var a = $(window).width()
    if (a>1000)mySwiper.params.slidesPerView = 4;
    if (a>480 && a<=640) mySwiper.params.slidesPerView = 3;
    if (a<=480) mySwiper.params.slidesPerView = 2;
    if (a<=320) mySwiper.params.slidesPerView = 1;
}
```